# How to loop using Pig for unique values

Tags: loops, apache-pig

I have a file that contains the census information which I would like to query using Pig.

The file format is as follows:

```
ID Name Year Gender State Count

1 Jones 1980   M      MA   100
```

I would like to get the percentage for each name for that state in that year for each year in the file

How can I loop through each of the years and calculate for each state the percentage of occurrences of each name?

The result should look as follows:

```
    1901 Jones MA 2%
    1901 Jones VT 3%
    1901 Smith MA 1%
    1901 Lee   VT 4%
    ....
    ....

    2016 Jones MA 2%
    2016 Jones VT 3%
    2016 Smith MA 1%
    2016 Lee   VT 4%
```

For every year in the table I need to break it down by state and within every state I need to calculate the percentage for each name given the count information.

Comment: can you please post the format of result you are expecting

Comment: Corrected original post to include the results I'm looking for

Comment: How is the percentage determined,for example 2%?

Comment: In the original file I have a count of the number of occurrences for Jones in MA in 1901 as 100. In the file I have a all names in MA for 1901, I can sum these up and get a total for all names in MA in 1901 e.g 5000 names in MA in 1901. Jones then appears 100/5000 * 100 = 2%.

Comment: @PigWolf Ah I see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to generate another relation with grouping by year state, join the dataset with the new relation by year,state and then get the percentages.

See below.

```
A = LOAD 'census_data' USING PigStorage('\t') as (int:id,name:chararray,year:chararray,gender:chararray,state:chararray,int:count);
B = GROUP A by (year,state);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (year,state),SUM(A.count) as occurances;
D = JOIN A BY (year,state),C BY (year,state);
E = FOREACH D GENERATE A::year,A::name,A::state,CONCAT(A::count/C::occurances,'%'); --If you get an error try A.year,A.name,A.state,CONCAT(A.count/C.occurances,'%');
DUMP E;
```

Comment: Thanks inquisitive_mind, that's a very smart way of solving the problem. In line 3, should the flatten be for A and not for group?

Comment: @PigWolf No it should be for the group since we are group A by 2 fields and then we want fields to be split from the group.I have not tested it but the logic should assist you to get your desired output